# Subscribe to manual cache in React-Query?

Tags: react-query

Started to experiment with react-query and was thinking if i could use it as a replacement for redux? I fint react-query to be easier to use in nextJS (especially if i want to set a state on the server) so hope there would be a `useQuery` that doesnt require a function, ie works similar to redux's `useSelect`.

Is something like this possible (this doesnt work but illustrates what i want to achieve)? Ie use react-query as cache data an be able to subscribe to that cache data.

```
function InputHeaderContainer() {
  return (
    <div>
      <InputHeader />
      <InputBar />
    </div>
  );
}

function InputBar() {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const inputValue = queryClient.getQueryData('INPUT_VALUE');

  const onSearchChange = (event) => {
    queryClient.setQueryData('INPUT_VALUE', event.target.value);
  };

  return <input onChange={onSearchChange} value={inputValue || ''} />;
}

function InputHeader() {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  // getQueryData doesnt subscribe to the state and useQuery req a function :(
  const inputValue = queryClient.getQueryData('INPUT_VALUE');

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{inputValue}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> so hope there would be a useQuery that doesnt require a function, ie works similar to redux's useSelect.

You do need to provide the actual queryFn, but that doesn't mean that you cannot achieve redux like state management:

```
const useTodos = (select) => useTodos(['todos'], fetchTodos, { select })
```

Thanks to `select`, you can create fine-grained subscriptions, like:

```
const todoCount = useTodos(todos => todos.length)
const firstTodo = useTodos(todos => todos[0])
```

and so on. You can of course abstract that further away in custom hooks, like `useTodoCount()`.

Components will only be subscribed to the result of the `select` function, so if you only use the todo count, the component won't re-render if one todo changes because the length of the array stays the same. (side node: This assumes either v4 of react-query, or `notfiyOnChangeProps: 'tracked'` being set. Otherwise, you'll still see re-renders because `isFetching` transitions).

Also, be advised that every subscription triggers a background refetch. This can be too aggressive if you plan on using the custom hook multiple times. This can be best customized by setting a `staleTime` no your query. This time tells react-query how long a resource is considered fresh. As long as it is fresh, data will come out of the cache only (no background updates). To only fetch once, set `staleTime: Infintiy`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @TkDodo. But i am talking about Redux in the sense of regular state updates, that have nothing to do with API request. 

I have created a sandbox to better illustrate how i would like to use react-query in some cases, ie just to get/set to the cache and subscribe to it. -> https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-haze-9cuxdv?file=/src/components.js 

It is pretty useless to provide a function in the example above, and it even overrides my initial state for the theme.

Comment: okay well why would you want to do that - trying to use an async state manager for synchronous, local state. We've come a looong way from separating server and client state from having everything in redux. I wouldn't make the same mistake and use a one-stop shop for everything again, just the other way around :) See also this discussion: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/discussions/2852

Comment: Wanted to do it because i think react-query worked great in nextjs serverside functions. Sometimes i want to set initial state from the server to the client. To not having to work with two variables for that state. Imagine `<SearchInput value={searchQuery ?? router.query?.searchQuery ?? ''} />` i could instead set the searchQuery state on the server.... I tried a redux implementation, but it was really troublesome to work with it on the server even with "next-redux-wrapper", zustand worked really great in my tests though and i see that you recommended it in the link as well :).

Comment: What i found troublesome to implement with react-query is a search input with dropdown list of suggestions for the current value in the input. Using down arrow key should update the search input but not the dropdown list. Similar to how google have their searchbar. This feature was how i started this quest with trying to modify react-query default behaviour.